# H2 is appearing halfway down a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a kind of banner with a title. But when I try putting the `<h2>` title in the `<div>`. It appears halfway down for some reason. I know I can fix it by putting `margin-top - 20px` or so but it makes me feel like something is wrong for me to have to do that.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/j5ba4ajo/3/):**

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
#player-opponent {
  width: 545px; 
  height: 40px; 
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "player-opponent">
  <h2>Player x vs player y<h2>
</div>
```

Comment: you can reset default margin on h2 to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a margin on `<h2>` by default. You have to remove it. To vertical center the text of the `<h2>` you have to set the `height` and `line-height` to the `height` of your container (`#player-opponent`):

```css
h2 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
}
#player-opponent {
  width: 545px; 
  height: 40px; 
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="player-opponent">
  <h2>Player x vs player y</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: ohhh see i did inspect element and it didnt look like it had a margin because the background was red. Now i look ,it turns a little orange because of the yellow margin. stupid question lol but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add: line-height:0; to the h2. This will fix it - or you can mess with the padding on the h2 if you wish. This will fix it without messing with your padding.

```
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    line-height:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0;` to the `h2` to avoid the default margin every browser adds to heading elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/07syo5zp/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to #player-opponent to center things up a better.  The margin on the h2 may or may not need any changes depending on your preference.

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is that **h2** is getting overflow so you can simply achieve it by

```
 h2 {
     overflow: auto;
  }

#player-opponent {
     width: 545px; 
     height: 40px; 
     background-color: red;

  }
```